# Get Client ComputerName for Process on Terminal Server

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm running a script to gather info for running apps on a terminal server. I would like to get the remote ComputerName of the user running the app but I'm only able to get the ComputerName of the Terminal Server instead. Any idea on how I could achieve that? Here's the part of my script to gather the info.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName MYTSSERVER | Where-Object {
  $_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0 -and
  $_.Name -eq "WINWORD.exe"
} | Select-Object CSName, ProcessName
```

Comment: FTR, the [`Win32_Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372.aspx) class doesn't have a property `MainWindowHandle`, so you can just drop that check.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the client hostname or IP address from the Word process, because that process is running locally on the Remote Desktop server. Remote Desktop login information is recorded in the eventlog, so you need to extract it from there. However, you need the remote username for finding the correct logon session, so you still need to run the WMI query first.

Example for a single Word process running on the Remote Desktop server:

```
$server = '...'

$p = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Computer $server -Filter "Name='WINWORD.exe'"
$u = $p.GetOwner().User

$fltr = "*logon type:`t`t`t10*new logon:*account name:`t`t$u"
$addr = Get-EventLog -Computer $server -LogName Security -InstanceId 4624 -Message $fltr -Newest 1 |
        Where-Object { $_.Message -match 'source network address:\s*(.*)' } |
        ForEach-Object { $matches[1] }
```

The filter for the eventlog query matches the most recent Remote Desktop login (event ID 4626, logon type 10) of the user who started the Word process (`` account name:`t`t$u ``).

That will just give you the client's IP address, though. If you require the hostname you need to resolve it via a reverse DNS lookup or get it from the host itself with another WMI query:

```
$hostname = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $addr |
            Select-Object -Expand CSName
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried the script inputting a server and it returns nothing.

I outputted the $fltr variable and here's the result:
*logon type:   10*new logon:*account name:  System.Management.ManagementBaseObject System.Management.ManagementBaseObject System.Management.ManagementBaseObject System.Management.ManagementBaseObject System.Manage
ment.ManagementBaseObject System.Management.ManagementBaseObject




I also tried declaring $u with a string and it didn't work either.

Comment: I tried the following, I'm getting something but that may be more useful.
foreach ($u in $p) {
$fltr = "*logon type:`t`t`t10*new logon:*account name:`t`t$u"
$addr = Get-EventLog -Computer $server -LogName Security -InstanceId 4624 -Message $fltr -Newest 1 |
        Where-Object { $_.Message -match 'source network address:\s*(.*)' } |
        ForEach-Object { $matches[1] }
$addr
}Get-EventLog : Log "Security" could not be read to completion due to the following error. This may have occurred because the log was cleared while still being read. Index 35139 is out of bounds.

Comment: My sample code assumes `$p` is a single object. If it isn't you need to add appropriate loops to the code, obviously.

Comment: I tried with a single object and I get the following: Get-EventLog : Log "Security" could not be read to completion due to the following error. This may have occurred because the log was cleared while still being read. Index 35139 is out of bounds.

Comment: Windows does track this information, so in principle it shouldn't be necessary to try to retrieve it from the event log.  I don't know whether there's a WMI interface, though.  If you can call the Win32 API, WTSQuerySessionInformation is your friend.

Comment: @Harry Johnston There's no such WMI for WTSQuerySessionInformation :(! I still don't know how to tackle that problem...

Comment: `WTSQuerySessionInformation()` is a Win32 API function. It's not available via WMI. [Related](https://serverfault.com/a/466677).

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Cool, this works to list all the currently active users! How can I query this list of users with a username to output this with my other script? Sorry, I'm not really good in programming :(.

Comment: @Harry Johnston and Ansgar Wiechers What would be the best is something like this: [RDPInfo]::ListUsers("MYSERVER") | Where-Object $_username -eq "SOMETHING" or [RDPInfo]::ListUsers("MYSERVER").Username. Can we do something like that?

Comment: How about you actually try it?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers The argument Property is empty, I don't really know what else to use to query [RDPInfo]::ListUsers("MYSERVER"). [RDPInfo]::ListUsers("MYSERVER").Equals require a boolean which is not useful in my case.